# call procedure with table datatype as a Input parameter

Tags: oracle, procedure, plsqldeveloper

I want to call this procedure in plsql developer.

```
procedure issue( ErrorCode out number,
                  ErrorText out varchar2,
                  No out number,
                  Date out date,
                  BCode in number,
                  BrCode in number,
                  ACode in varchar2,
                  TCode in number,
                  pi_docElement_InputData IN DocElement_InputData);
```

the last input parameter is this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "DOCELEMENT_INPUTDATA" as Table Of Prepaid_Element_Doc
```

and the Prepaid_Element_Doc is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "PREPAID_ELEMENT_DOC" as object(
            A NUMBER(4),
            B NUMBER(3),
            C number(4)
  )
```

I need to enter 2 'PREPAID_ELEMENT_DOC' as a input of procedure but I don't how to do that.

```
select issue(801,802,'A',1,???) from dual;
```

Comment: You can't call a procedure in a `select` list. For that you would need a function.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the constructors for the two database types, for example

```sql
DocElement_InputData(PREPAID_ELEMENT_DOC(1,2,3),PREPAID_ELEMENT_DOC(4,5,6))
```

The above code creates a `DocElement_InputData` that contains two `PREPAID_ELEMENT_DOC`.

Refer to the Oracle documentation for your Oracle version.

This is for Oracle 19c

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Type-Constructor-Expressions.html#GUID-E8A491DE-18BA-4A1E-8CE2-BBA43E5C52D6

Answer (score 0):

You can call procedure with table datatype in such way

```
select 
    issue
    (
        801,
        802,
        'A',
        1, 
        (DOCELEMENT_INPUTDATA
            (
                PREPAID_ELEMENT_DOC(1, 2, 3), 
                PREPAID_ELEMENT_DOC(3, 4, 5)
            )
        )
    ) 
from 
    dual;
```